# TSQL : Max date but include other variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find records with the max date, easy enough, but it doesn't work when I want additional atrributes.

I have 3 tables.

Table 1 = Student.

```
Columns STid, STname
Value    1, John
         2, Bob Lee
         3, Jane
```

Table 2 = Test.

```
Columns Testid, STid, Date, Grade
Value    1, 1, 20/05/2018, A
         2, 2, 20/05/2018, B
         3, 3, 20/05/2018, D
         4, 1, 30/06/2018, C
         5, 2, 30/06/2018, C
         6, 3, 30/06/2018, B
```

What I want is the grades of each student from the last test.

The output should be ..

```
Columns STname, Date, Grade
Value    John, 1, 30/06/2018, C
         Bob Lee, 2, 30/06/2018, C
         Jane, 3, 30/06/2018, B
```

When I try the below, it works fine but I need the grade.

```
SELECT STNAME, MAX(T.DATE)
FROM STUDENT S, TEST T
WHERE S.STID = T.STID
GROUP BY STNAME
```

Unfortunately the below won't work.

```
SELECT STNAME, MAX(T.DATE), T.GRADE
FROM STUDENT S, TEST T
WHERE S.STID = T.STID
GROUP BY STNAME
```

Or the below just bring back everything.

```
SELECT STNAME, MAX(T.DATE), T.GRADE
FROM STUDENT S, TEST T
WHERE S.STID = T.STID
GROUP BY STNAME, T.GRADE.
```

I suspect the answer lies with a `subquery`, but I can't get it to work either.

```
SELECT STNAME, T.DATE, T.GRADE
FROM STUDENT S, TEST T
WHERE S.STID = T.STID
AND T.DATE = (SELECT MAX(T.DATE)
             FROM STUDENT S, TEST T
             WHERE S.STID = T.STID )

OR 

SELECT STNAME, T.DATE, T.GRADE
FROM STUDENT S, TEST T
WHERE S.STID = T.STID
AND T.DATE = (SELECT MAX(T2.DATE)
             FROM STUDENT S2, TEST T2
             WHERE S.STID = S2.STID )
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need `row_number()` function :

```
select t.*
from (select s.stid, s.STname, t.Date, t.Grade, 
             row_number() over (partition by s.stid order by t.date desc) as seq
      from student s inner join
           test t
           on t.stid = s.stid
      ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server also supports lateral joins for this type of problem.  These can often have better performance than using window functions:

```
select s.*, t.date, t.grade
from student s outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from test t
      where t.stid = s.stid
      order by t.date desc
     ) t;
```